# Nginx reverse proxy allow only authenticated users to spring boot api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nginx, spring-security

I have a task of replacing Zuul reverse proxy with Nginx.
Security in Zuul proxy is implemented with `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class ZuulSecurity(...) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                .sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(*dennyPatterns).denyAll()
                .antMatchers(*loginPatterns).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage(loginUrl)
    }
}
```

Spring boot api services are protected in similar way with `@EnableWebSecurity`

I replace Zuul reverse proxy with Nginx as reverse proxy.

How can I enforce security on Nginx, so that no unathenticated request is `proxy_pass`'ed to backend api servcies? - Other words, I would like to validate on Nginx if request is made by an authenticated user (with some exception for loginPatterns urls). Which one of [nginx/admin-guide/security-controls](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/) should I study?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with [configuring-subrequest-authentication/](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/)